# Assigning values to an array in Bash shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I've got a plain text file containing track titles & artists separated by a dash.
I want to put all the titles into one array (`TRK_TITLE[]`).
At the same time create an array of artists (`ARTIST[]`).
Below is the code I'm using:

```
CTR=0
# Read in the track title file
while read line

do 

# Add to the counter
    CTR=$((CTR + 1))

# Get the track number
    TRK_NUM[$CTR]=$CTR

# VARIOUS is set by command line parameter
if [ $VARIOUS = "FALSE" ]
then
# -- THIS BIT WORKS! ------------------------------
TRK_TITLE[$CTR]=${line}
# ARTISTS determined by grandparent directory name.
ARTIST[$CTR]="$ARTISTS"

# THE BIT THAT DOESN'T WORK AS IT APPEARS --------- 
else
# VARIOUS has been set to TRUE
# Get the track title
# 1st, Make sure I'm dealing with something sensible
echo "$line"
# Get the length of the line,
# just for information
total_len=${#line}
# Find the position of the "-"
dash_pos=`expr index "$line" -`

# These lines prove that the syntax works
echo "${line:0:$dash_pos - 2}"

echo "${line:$dash_pos + 1}"

echo $total_len "--" $dash_pos 
# Now add to arrays
TRK_TITLE[$CTR]="${line:0:$dash_pos -2}"
#TRK_TITLE="${line:0:$dash_pos -2}"

ARTIST[$CTR]="${line:$dash_pos + 1}"
#ARTIST="${line:$dash_pos + 1}"

#Now to see the output
echo $TRK_TITLE[$CTR] "is Track"
#echo "$TRK_TITLE is Track"

echo $ARTIST[$CTR] "is Artist"
#echo "$ARTIST is Artist"

fi

# keep going until the end
# Variable name used for input file
done < "$FYL_2_USE"
```

When the hashes are where they are the output is thus:

> Dedicated to the One I Love - The Mamas and The Papas
>
> Dedicated to the One I Love
>
> The Mamas and The Papas
>
> 53 -- 29
>
> [19] is Track
>
> [19] is Artist

If the hashes are swapped on the variable and echo
statements, the output is thus:

> Dedicated to the One I Love - The Mamas and The Papas
>
> Dedicated to the One I Love
>
> The Mamas and The Papas
>
> 53 -- 29
>
> Dedicated to the One I Love is Track
>
> The Mamas and The Papas is Artist
>
> Shell is Gnu Bash V4.1.0(2)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace:

```
echo $TRK_TITLE[$CTR] "is Track"
echo $ARTIST[$CTR] "is Artist"
```

with:

```
echo ${TRK_TITLE[$CTR]} "is Track"
echo ${ARTIST[$CTR]} "is Artist"
```

your script will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my obvious mistake Tomasz How could I not see the that?